# How to define multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have some code here:
First a simple random # generator and a array-choosing function:

```
function Rand(min, max) {
  return parseFloat(Math.floor(Math.random() * max - min + 1))) + parseFloat(min);
}

function Choose(arr) {
  //Returns an element from an array at random.
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

and second a Card shuffler:

```
function CardDeck() {
  var Cd = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"];
  var H = [];
  var S = [];
  var D = [];
  var C = [];
  var Result = [];
  var Dk = document.getElementById("Deck Count").value;

  for (i = 0; i < Cd.length; i++) {
    S[i] = Cd[i] + " of Spades";
    H[i] = Cd[i] + " of Hearts";
    C[i] = Cd[i] + " of Clubs";
    D[i] = Cd[i] + " of Diamonds";
  }

  if (Dk == "4") {
    P = S.concat(C, D, H);
  } else if (Dk == "5") {
    var St = [];
    for (i = 0; i < Cd.length; i++) {
      St[i] = Cd[i] + " of Stars";
    }
    P = S.concat(C, D, H, St);
  } else if (Dk == "6") {
    var Rk = [];
    var Wh = [];
    for (i = 0; i < Cd.length; i++) {
      Rk[i] = Cd[i] + " of Rackets";
      Wh[i] = Cd[i] + " of Wheels";
    }
    P = S.concat(C, D, H, Rk, Wh);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < Dk * Cd.length; i++) {
    var Q = Choose(P);
    R = P.indexOf(Q);
    Result[i] = (i + 1) + ": " + Q;
    P = P.slice(0, R).concat(P.slice(R + 1));
  }

  document.getElementById("Cards").innerHTML = Result.join("\n");
}
```

Is there an easy way to make this faster or at least declare the arrays faster instead of just doing a=[],b=[]... for each as that can be time-consuming and tedious.

Additionally, is there a way to get a better RNG with a longer period in base JS (no libraries, as this was built on base JS)

Comment: It's not faster necessarily, but it would probably be more convenient to use an object with these arrays as properties, or use an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the suit names in another array it eliminates a lot of variables; then using `apply` with `concat` can get them all into `Result` in one shot:

```
function CardDeck() {
  var Cd = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"];
  var Result = [];
  var Dk = document.getElementById("Deck Count").value;

  // Put the suit names into a new array
  var suitNames = [" of Spades", " of Hearts", " of Clubs", " of Diamonds"];
  if (Dk == "5") {
    suitNames.push(" of Stars");
  } else if (Dk == "6") {
    suitNames.push(" of Rackets");
    suitNames.push(" of Wheels");
  }

  // Create all suit stacks as an array of arrays
  var suits = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Cd.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < suitNames.length; j++) {
        if(i===0) suits.push([]);
        suits[j].push(Cd[i] + suitNames[j]);
    }
  }

  // Combine all cards into a single array
  var P = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], suits);

  // Shuffle the deck
  for (i = 0; i < P.length; i++) {
    var Q = Choose(P);
    R = P.indexOf(Q);
    Result[i] = (i + 1) + ": " + Q;
    P = P.slice(0, R).concat(P.slice(R + 1));
  }

  document.getElementById("Cards").innerHTML = Result.join("\n");

}
```

Here's a running sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/b4rf3ne2/

Is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes this is perfect as it also allows for many suits to be made at once! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid typing `var` over and over like this: `var H=[], S=[], D=[], C=[];` But otherwise it's hard to get more concise than what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like: declare one array-root, then declare a lot of subarrays in a for loop:

```
var arrays = [];
var nmbOfAr = 20;
for(int i = 0; i < nmbOfAr; i++){
    arrays[i] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 I think we can make marginal improvements.

```
let {S, H, C, D} = Cd.reduce((state, cardType, idx) => {
  state.S.push(cardType + ' of Spades');
  state.H.push(cardType + ' of Hearts');
  state.C.push(cardType + ' of Clubs');
  state.C.push(cardType + ' of Diamonds');
  return state;   
}, {
  S: [],
  H: [],
  C: [],
  D: [],
});
```